# arbor.js layout algorithm

Tags: arbor.js

How can I add my own layout algorithm which would work with the rest of arbor.js framework? This question hasn't been answered anywhere I know. However I believe this is a very important feature that needs to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Arbor is a framework built with the main purpose of rendering Force-Directed graphs... If you need another layout algorithm, I suggest you to find another framework that maybe suits better your needs.